# specific column filter with data tables

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//initialisation code
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",



        } );
    } );

    var asInitVals = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("tfoot input").each( function (i) {
            asInitVals[i] = this.value;
        } );


        $("tfoot input").focus( function () {
            if ( this.className == "search_init" )
            {
                this.className = "";
                this.value = "";
            }
        } );
        $("tfoot input").blur( function (i) {
            if ( this.value == "" )
            {
                this.className = "search_init";
                this.value = asInitVals[$("tfoot input").index(this)];
            }
        } );

        var oTable = $('.exam').dataTable( {
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
            },
            "bStateSave": true,
            "fnInitComplete": function() {
                var oSettings = $('.exam').dataTable().fnSettings();
                for ( var i=0 ; i<oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length ; i++ ){
                    if(oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch.length>0){
                        $("tfoot input")[i].value = oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch;
                        $("tfoot input")[i].className = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        } );

        $("tfoot input").keyup( function () {
            /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
            oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
        } );

    } );
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="example" class = "exam" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pretty" align="center">
```

I am new to jquery programming. when I viwew the table in browsers I see the error:

> Data Tables warning (table id = 'example'): can not reinitialise Data
>   Table. To retrieve the data table object for this table, pass no
>   arguments or see the  docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

how to solve this  problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to initialize the same table twice.  First you are running

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",



    } );
} );
```

Which is trying to initialize datatables on the table with the ID of example.  Then you try to initialize it again here:

```
var oTable = $('.exam').dataTable( {
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnInitComplete": function() {
            var oSettings = $('.exam').dataTable().fnSettings();
            for ( var i=0 ; i<oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length ; i++ ){
                if(oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch.length>0){
                    $("tfoot input")[i].value = oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch;
                    $("tfoot input")[i].className = "";
                }
            }
        }
    } );
```

Here you are initializing a table with the class of exam.  The table with the class exam, and the ID of example are the same table in this case.  The error is basically saying, hey I already initialized this table once, I cant do it again.

Remove the first block of code and it should solve your problem.